# Converted methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, xampp

I'm looking at a project I've made in Laravel 4, and I have the below methods

```
        return Redirect::route('home')
        ->withDomain($domain)
        ->withAvailable($available);
```

which I know they are convert to

```
        ->with("domain",$domain)
        ->with("available",$available);
```

,I know that cause it's used to work. I've seen this in one of [Jeffrey Way](https://tutsplus.com/author/jeffreyway/) videos. But now it's not working, it promts that the methods are undefined.

#### Edit

If I run `composer update`

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0
    - Installation request for way/database dev-master -> satisfiable by way/database[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA3
    - way/database dev-master requires illuminate/validation 4.1.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.1.x-dev], illuminate/validation[4.1.x-dev, v4
.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4
.1.24, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.0.0-BETA2, 4.1.x-dev].
    - don't install illuminate/validation 4.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.10|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.11|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.12|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.14|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.15|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.17|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.18|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.19|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.21|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.23|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.24|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.5|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.7|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/validation v4.1.9|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4
, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].
```

My `composer.json`

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
    "way/generators": "dev-master",
    "way/database": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/controllers/user/cart",
        "app/controllers/user/order",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/lib/commands",
        "app/lib/curl",
        "app/lib/debug",
        "app/lib"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: Can you show the exact message you have for those errors? The code in the current `master` of Laravel works [exactly as you said](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php#L198).

Comment: @raina77ow This is an old project, back then was Laravel 4.0

Comment: I see. Well, it seems that your version of the framework was indeed put in place before [this particular commit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/97bbfe6f09e7b0a5143d65568e886f7a1ace2f9c). If your project is under some version control, just check the history on the related file to see what went wrong. My guess (quite blind, though) is that by some reasons your framework has been 'downgraded' to that pre-`__call` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even Laravel 4.0 provided `withName()` for Response. What's happening to you is at least odd.

Open the file:

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse.php
```

And check if you have

```
/**
 * Dynamically bind flash data in the session.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array  $parameters
 * @return void
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (starts_with($method, 'with'))
    {
        return $this->with(snake_case(substr($method, 4)), $parameters[0]);
    }

    throw new \BadMethodCallException("Method [$method] does not exist on Redirect.");
}
```

This is the code the provide those dynamic calls to `with()` and it was added by Taylor in 2013-10-03.

If you don't have this part of the code, you might have a Laravel source code problem, delete Laravel:

```
rm -rf vendor/laravel
```

And install it again:

```
composer update
```

Or you can just do that update before anything else, because if it's a very old project, you might just not have it downloaded.

Comment: I guess it's safe to remove `vendor/laravel`. There is not such a method in `RedictRespone` .

Comment: Does this line `"laravel/framework": "4.0.*",` in my composer file prevent for being updated?

Comment: Try update composer usign `"laravel/framework": "4.0.10",`, this is the last 4.0 version of Laravel and it has that method.